# Catch the Cancel state from the Save Dialog for a MS Word document about to be closed with unsaved changes

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, add-in

I have a Microsoft Word Add-in developed in C#. When a user tries to close a document with unsaved changes, the Save dialog box is shown. Is there a way to capture if the user clicks cancel on the Save dialog?

The DocumentBeforeClose event is annoyingly fired before the Save dialog is shown and it appears an event isn't fired encapsulating the Save Dialog event.

Why I need this:
If the user closes the last document, I need to do some clean up on my Add-in tool bar. However, if I do the clean up in the DocumentBeforeClose event and the user clicks cancel, the Add-in tool bar state is incorrect.

**Edit/Update:**

As Rob Allen suggested, I am now using the ShutDown event to do cleanup of my parent object and the BeforeClose event for pre-close validation of my parent object. My validation needs the document to be saved and tries to do that in a method called by BeforeClose. If the document has never been saved before, the Save As dialog appears. If the user clicks Cancel a COMException is thrown and I catch that. Then the Save/Don't Save/Cancel dialog appears. **If the user clicks Don't Save, the ShutDown event is not fired.** If the user saves from the Save As dialog, saves from the second dialog, or hits cancel on the 2nd dialog, everything functions correctly.

```
private void WordDocument_BeforeClose(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    this.WordDocument.Save();
  }
  catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException a)
  {
    log.Error(a.Message);
  }
}

private void WordDocument_Shutdown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Parent cleanup.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Document Shutdown event instead. Docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.shutdown.aspx)

From the 'Remarks' section:

> This is the last event to be called in a Document as it unloads. Use this event for any additional clean up.
>
> In a document-level customization, the application domain for the assembly unloads when the document host item shuts down.
>
> In an application-level add-in, the application domain does not unload when the document host item shuts down. Also, the underlying document object is no more available. To access the document before it shuts down use CloseEvent instead.

Comment: Shutdown seems to be fired where I need it. However, when I try to access any of the (Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document) Document's properties, there is an underlying COM Exception stating the "Object has been deleted." I guess this makes sense... however, I was hoping to use the document's name so that I could remove the name from a list of active documents. Any way around this?

Comment: Do you need to really know the open documents, or is Word's Application.Quit method firing sufficient

Comment: Or even a count of open documents in general for that matter

Comment: It seems that the ShutDown event is inconsistent... It doesn't always fire for Save, and Don't save. (It correctly never fires for cancel)... Thoughts?

Comment: Isn't Application.Quit used to close Word? The case I'm dealing with is when the last document itself is closed, but Word stays open.

Comment: Yes. Application.Quit closes Word. It sounds like you want to clean up your objects before Word quits - how many people really leave Word open without a document? Are you loading your code on Document Open or when Word loads? Which is really the most appropriate place? If I close all of my documents, then start a new one, do I need to wait for your code to finish clean up and restart?

Comment: I do not know how often a user closes just the document instead of Word itself, however, it's probably > 0, so I need to handle the case. I am loading the add-in code when Word loads and the document code when a document is opened/created. The integration points are in the correct places and there is no lag because the document cleanup/setup only entails removing/adding event handlers to the document and disabling/enabling the add-in buttons.  So back to the problem: The ShutDown event is inconsistent and there seems to be a threading issue or something of that nature. Thoughts?

Comment: What I am stuck is why you need a list of open documents vs just knowing how many are left open.

Comment: I refactored my code to not need a list of open documents anymore and moved the appropriate logic into the _BeforeClose and _Shutdown methods for the word document. So that's not a problem anymore. However, as I stated, unless I'm going crazy, the ShutDown event is not being fired consistently which is now the main problem.

Comment: In that case, post the new error, new code in your question and we can tackle it.

Comment: I updated my question. So I narrowed the problem down to trying to save a new document in the BeforeClose event. If I try .Save(), hit cancel, then the Save/Don't Save/Cancel dialog shows. If I hit "don't save", the ShutDown event is not fired. Any other flow (saving, hitting cancel, etc) fires/does not fire the correct events.

Comment: Joe, that makes sense in this context. If the user hits cancel, the document remains open and unsaved....

Comment: Sorry, I must have been unclear. If the user hits cancel, the document remains open, unsaved, and ShutDown doesn't fire, which is correct. If the user hits save, the document saves, closes, and the ShutDown event fires, which is correct. However, if the user clicks "Don't Save", the document closes without saved changes (which is correct), but the ShutDown event does NOT fire.

Comment: Because your answer did solve my initial question, I marked yours as the answer. I created a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749411/shutdown-event-is-not-always-fired-when-saving-a-word-ducment-during-beforeclose) to detail the new problem I am having.