# Shutdown event is not always fired when Saving a Word document during BeforeClose event

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I have a Microsoft Word Add-in using `VSTO` and `c#`.

For each document, I am using the document ShutDown event to do cleanup of my parent object and the BeforeClose event for pre-close validation of my parent object. My validation needs the document to be saved and tries to do that in the BeforeClose event.

If the document has never been saved before, the Save As dialog appears. If the user clicks Cancel a `COMException` is thrown and I catch that properly. Then the `Save/Don't Save/Cancel` dialog appears (which normally shows up for a document that is about to be closed with unsaved changes). If the user saves from the first Save As dialog or saves from the second save dialog the `ShutDown` event is fired correctly. **However, If the user clicks Don't Save on the second dialog, the ShutDown event is not fired.**

```
private void WordDocument_BeforeClose(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    this.WordDocument.Save();
  }
  catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException a)
  {
    log.Error(a.Message);
  }
}

private void WordDocument_Shutdown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Parent cleanup.
}
```